# Не запускается PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap

Не могу запустить PhoneGap. Вроде уж все установил, и JDK, и Phonegap CLI.. а все равно при запуске вот такая картинка и ничего нельзя нажать

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Ещё надо Andoid SDK и Node JS поставить.